# How can I keep track of upcoming Java versions?

Tags: java, windows, deployment, auto-update

I want to keep track of new versions of Java. I know there is an auto-update feature but I do not want to use it because of regulatory restrictions.

I have to confirm that our software works with the new Java version each time a new version of Java is released.

I want to build packages with the latest version so I want to be notified by mail when a new version arrives.

I found this website: http://java.com/de/download/faq/release_dates.xml and this txt file: http://java.com/applet/JreCurrentVersion2.txt

Is there a way to get a mail when it changes? Or even better, does anyone have an idea on how to do a script that downloads the latest version to my local server and starts building my package? What would be the programs needed?

Comment: When you get an update for your java means a newer version is out for general releases. If you want beta releases use http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ea-jsp-142245.html

Comment: Currently I only want to test released versions. Thank you for the hint anyway.

Comment: I'm a little confused, in one paragraph you said you did not want to  auto-update java, but in the last paragraph, it looks like you're asking for a script that auto-updates java.  What is the specific restriction you're trying to comply with?

Comment: I have to check manually if the new version will work as intended with our software that uses Java. So I basically want the notification that there is a new version out by e-mail so I am reminded of this task.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the autoupdater in "ask before installing" mode as notification? Or maybe one of http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/detect-website-change-notification/ on the second link?

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3rd party service like [Touchpine](https://touchpine.com/) to monitor Java version updates. As of today there are currently [Java](https://touchpine.com/app/java) and [Java SE](https://touchpine.com/app/java-se) monitored. If needed you can request other software to be added. It's usually done within 48 hours.

As for automating the whole process - there are **personalised RSS** feeds and **API** on [Touchpine](https://touchpine.com/) which you can use for automation of the whole process.